# control text align and float in iframe

Tags: html, css, xhtml, iframe, text-align

I have a iframe with a width of 450 with text inside and I want to align this text on the right hand side of the iframe. I don't have access to the iframe to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't have access to the iframe to change it.

Then I'm afraid what you want to do is impossible. The [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents any and all access to the DOM of that iFrame.

You would have to use a server-side script to fetch the iframe's contents.

Comment: The content is a facebook like button, heres a example url: http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;font=verdana&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=35

Comment: @pijor nope, not possible, sorry. Maybe play around with the iframe's width if the size is always going to be the same...

Comment: it's  not going to be the same because it randomly will put a name of someone who liked it in the iframe.

Comment: @pjiorwierjog You could make your own with the FB SDK: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: seems quite over kill for just aligning text

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this if it is XS (Cross-Site)

This could only be achieved if you had access to the iframe'd file.